# Proof that $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \{\frac{3m}{7n}\| m\in\mathbb{Z},n\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: arithmetic, rational-numbers

It seems to me that the statement is true and I thought about prooving it by showing that if you take any rational number of form $\frac{a}{b}$ you can cross multiply it with $\frac{3m}{7n}$ and get $7an=3bm$ you can always find a solution to the expression and it means that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of the group. However I struggle to formalize my proof.

Comment: $a/b=\frac{a}{b} \times \frac{3}{7} \times \frac{7}{3}= \frac{3(7a)}{7(3b)} $ .

Comment: Though why would you need this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks! Just a question from an assignment that I couldn't find a way to formalize.